# Unable to disconnect battery connector in my Asus Laptop

Tags: laptop, battery

I have watched multiple videos where when they moved the slider, the white battery connector just pops out. However, mine just stays in place and does not budge when I try to move it. Am I doing something wrong or is there something wrong with the laptop?
[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOodQ.jpg)

Comment: Your connector has 2 locking pins preventing you from pulling the connector away from the socket. You need to push down the 2 tabs bottom left and bottom right in your image, so they are below the level of the socket.

Answer (score -1):

Once you slide back the cover you can just lift up the connector. The black parts visible are just there to keep the connector flush with the socket. I ran into one of these a few days ago. Here's a video showing the process.

https://youtu.be/JHPde7WFMr4?t=92

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not easy to read (nor decipher).